# mysql timestamp not in epoch

Tags: php, mysql

I've set a field in my mysql db to "timestamp" yet it still returns time in queries as yyyy:mm:dd: time. I set it as a timestamp because I wanted milliseconds since 1970. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: mysql timestamps have a 1 second resolution. they do not include milliseconds, but you can trivially multiply by 1000 to convert  into milliseconds, e.g. `select unix_timestamp(timestampfield) * 1000`.

Comment: Until 5.6.4, where `TIMESTAMPS` *can* have milliseconds. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? In PHP, you can convert a MySQL timestamp to seconds from the epoch using the function `strtotime`. You could also, if absolutely desperate, use string parsing to get each part of the timestamp and calculate the seconds from the epoch yourself.

Comment: php, then ajaxing back to JS , was hoping for a way to extract epoch directly from the mysql return, cheers, will try it out

Comment: You can do it in MySQL.  Check out my previous answer, storing the Unix timestamp as an INT, then calling `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to do more readable queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the Unix timestamp as an INT.  Then when you call it from the DB you can process it server side to get what you want.